# How can i get correlation between categorical and continuous variables?

Tags: python, numpy, correlation, categorical-data

I want to get the correlation between a **categorical** variable and a **continuous** variable.

I used `np.corrcoef` to look at the stackoverflow question and try to do the same. However, the correlation is to see the relationship between x and y by fitting the data. I wonder if it makes sense to derive the correlation of y (**numerical variable**) after replacing x (**categorical variable**) with dummy variable.

For example, a categorical variable called Type of fire has four categories, A type, B type, C type, D type, and y is a numerical variable called fireman manpower, and `np.corrcoef` is used.

As a result, the correlation coefficient between Type A and fireman manpower is -0.2.

When analyzing this data, did it make meaningful results?

Answer (score 0):

Point Biserial Correlation is the correlation that can reflect the relation between continuous and categorical features.

In python you can use:

```
from scipy import stats
stats.pointbiserialr(x, y)
```